# Access Windows 10 Safe Mode from startup

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode, ransomware

I have an Asus machine running up-to-date Windows 10. With all the Ransomware panic going around ittakes me back to when I was victim of a type-3 Ransomware attack (lockout). The way I managed to resolve it was by getting in through safe mode and corrupt the malware's files that way.

Unfortunately, it seems currently the only way to access safe mode is through a boot parameter that can only be set from WITHIN Windows 10.

Is it still possible for me to get into safe mode without booting in 'normal' mode first, should I need to again for similar reasons?

Comment: Make backups. Never worry about ransomware again!

Comment: @djsmiley2k Not always an option, mostly financially. Plus, back up too often and the RWare will be in the backup too.

Comment: ... How much is your data worth?. This isn't the place for discussions anyway, feel free to drop by [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) where we can chat!

Comment: Create a system recovery USB drive and you can get into safe mode with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to boot when the disk will not boot :

1. [Use the Recovery Drive app](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-recovery-drive-windows-10) to create a system recovery USB drive
   that can be used as the boot device.
   [image]
2. The old methods of  <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
   still work, on condition that you are not using UEFI BIOS & SSD.
   In any case, if fast boot is configured then the opportunity window
   becomes too small to succeed ([Microsoft link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/05/22/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before/)).
3. Use a boot CD/USB.

To be completely safe from all problems, best practice is to keep around
a small recovery USB as well as a boot CD/USB (or be able to download one
if disaster arrives), just in case.

Comment: Are 1 and 3 the only alternatives to 2 if I am using UEFI BIOS & SSD?

Comment: Yes - read the linked Microsoft article for explanations.